# How to receive socket events in sails.js 0.10?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, sails.js

I've a model called `Collection.js` and it looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        title: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
        description: {
            type: 'text',
            required: false
        },
        sessions: {
            collection: 'session',
            via: 'collection'
        }
    }
}
```

As I understand [this](http://beta.sailsjs.org/#!documentation/reference/Upgrading/Upgrading.html) document, the message, which is sent via the socket when a new model instance was created, is available through the models name.

So I have this snipped in my `app.coffee` file:

```
socket = io.connect()

socket.on 'collection', ->
    console.log 'hey'
```

I've validated that the 'environment' works, because I get notifications on `socket.on 'connect'. -> console.log 'hey'`**, but I don't get any for model events like create or destory a record!**

Blueprints are activated. What do I have to change?

## Update

Here some more code, how I want to use it:

```
$('document').ready ->
    noData = $('#list tr')
    socket.get '/collection', (res) ->
        createList(res)
```

So, the socket should be subscribed to all events.

Later I want to hook on this events:

```
socket.on 'collection', (res) ->
    socket.get '/collection', (res) ->
        recreateList(res)
```

But get never notified.

## Update 2

My controller `CollectionController.js` looks like:

```
module.exports = {
    manage: function(req, res) {
        Collection.watch(req);
        return res.view();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am also having the same issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, you will be subscribed to all the instances returned by the `find` blueprint when you do `socket.get('/collection')`, so you should be notified when any of them are updated or destroyed.  However, you won't get notifications about records being *created* unless you either a) explicitly call `Collection.watch(req)` in your Sails code, or b) set `autoWatch` to true in `/config/blueprints.js`.  See the [reference for .watch()](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/websockets/resourceful-pubsub/watch.html) and [.subscribe()](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/websockets/resourceful-pubsub/subscribe.html) for more info.

The general idea is that for a large-scale app that could have thousands or millions of users, it doesn't make sense to send out notifications to every connected socket whenever a new user is created.  Sockets should only be notified about changes to instances they specifically subscribed to.

**Update**

After finally getting to review the code in question, it looks like there are a few things going on that need attention:

1. The socket event being listened for in the code is `Collection`, but it needs to be `collection`.  `Collection` is the model's globalized ID, but `collection` is its *identity*, which is used as the event name.  Case matters here.
2. Similarly, the `autoWatch` setting in `/config/blueprints.js` is case sensitive; you have it as `autowatch`.
3. By default, you don't get socket notifications from the blueprints for events that you yourself trigger.  You can use the callback from the socket request methods instead (i.e. `socket.post(url, data,  callback)`).  This allow you to respond differently to actions that you triggered yourself, rather than ones that were triggered by someone else.  If you really want to get your own socket notifications from the blueprints, you can set `mirror: true` in `/config/blueprints.js`.

It looks like `mirror` needs to be added to the docs, although it's mainly a dev tool that you may regret using in production ;)

Once I changed those three things, the code worked fine!

Comment: My controller action contains `Collection.watch(req);`. I performed a `socket.delete` after I called `socket.get`, but I don't get notified afterwards and it's not working. With Sails 0.9 everything was working flawlessly. Is it possible that there is a mistake in the new `sails.io.js`?

Comment: I see that the websocket is writing data `verbose: websocket writing 6:::4+[{"...` but it never hits `socket.on`.

Comment: The `Collection.watch(req)` needs to be called in response to a *socket* request; calling it in the action that serves your view (which responds to an HTTP request) won't work.  As a test, try turning `autoWatch` on.  However, `socket.delete` after `socket.get` should result in a notification being received; a quick test over here has it running fine.  I'd try `sails log --silly` and check that the socket is being subscribed to the instances correctly.

Comment: `silly: Subscribed to the Collection with id=42 (room :: sails_model_collection_42:destroy)` It looks like the subscription works! What is the channel name?

Comment: Does sails make for each model instance a separate room? Why?

Comment: Is collection a reserved word?

Comment: Yes, each instance gets its own room, so that different sockets can subscribe to different instances.  The room names should be irrelevant to your implementation.  On the front end, you're listening for the "collection" event, which is correct.  No, `collection` is not reserved.  Maybe check that your coffeescript is being compiled into `socket.on('collection', function(res){...})`?

Comment: I've pushed all my code to this repo: https://github.com/openscript/location_stalker

I don't want to be unfriendly throwing with all my code to you, but I don't see any other way. I can offer you a beer in Zurich :-)

Comment: Go with scott on this, deleting my answer. Scott is part of the core team, I understood the docs differently. @ScottGress

Comment: @Sam Thanks--I'll look it over when I get a minute.  Hopefully it's something simple!

Comment: Ok, looked over the code and updated my answer with the necessary info to get things up and running.

Comment: Thank you very much @Scott! The most important part for my understanding was "you don't get socket notifications from the blueprints for events that you yourself trigger".